# Prevent calling "show" event of jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery tabs in MVC application. Based of whcih tab is selected I wan't to a message and cancel the show event of selected tab.

Is there any way to cancel the "show" event of jquery tabs?

**Code:**

```
$tabs = $("#resultTabs").tabs();

   var selectedTab = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');

    $tabs.tabs("select", (selectedTab));

       $tabs.tabs({
        select: function (e) {
            if (selectedTab != 4 && GetQuickViewValidation()) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                return;
            }
        },
        show: function (event, ui) {
            LoadResultTab(true, false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please create a codepen for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Requirement
>
> - You want to prevent calling tab showing
>
> **Solution:**
>
> - You need to use `beforeActivate: function(event, ui)` event for tab
> - You will be able to access that clicked `event` here
> - Use `event.preventDefault();` to stop tab change event

Please check below code :

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
    if (confirm('Do you want to tab switch?')==false) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent switching tabs
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>You are wathing <b>tab 1</b> here.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>You are wathing <b>tab 2</b> here.</p>
    <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>You are wathing <b>tab 3</b> here.</p>
    <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here you will be able to switch tab only by accepting `OK`.